# How to do a order based testing in Geb and Spock using Groovy, I want to verify if the given values are in order from UI

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am using Geb and Spock with Groovy and got stuck on testing with order and need to verify from UI.

Ex- I have 5 values which i need to get the texts from UI and compare whether they are matching from my groovy file

Groovy class with test step-
and:

```
_ "I verify for the values is displayed as per the order"
baseclass.verifyOrder(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

base file-

```
void verifyOrder(List<String> Order){
  for(String check:Order){
    locator.displayed
    String st = locator.text()
    assert check == st
  }
}
```

From above I am getting the result as true even though I changed order of the list
(Ex- b replace a).

What i want is when the order is not correct it should fail and give pass when it is in correct order from UI. Can someone help me on this do i need check the locator or am I missing any logic in code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Try adding some `println(st)` in your code.  See if it's what you expect.  I don't follow the code you posted.  The `locator.displayed` seems like an expression and not a statement, so I don't know what that is doing.